# Sending APNS message with "content-available" prevents message delivery?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

Having a tough time with APNS.  My app is receiving notifications in the foreground if the request is just:

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : "do_move;E18"
  }
}
```

The app is properly intercepting the message in the DidReceiveRemoteNotification handler (C# Xamarin)

If I add the content-available key, the message is no longer intercepted by the app when running in the foreground.  Here is the message I am sending:

```
 {
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : "do_move;E18",
    "content-available" : 1
  }
}
```

I am using Easy APNs Provider (App Store for Mac) to generate the messages to APNS.  The App is downloaded from TestFlight.

My app is has Required Background Modes remote-notification
and Enable Push Notifications in Entitlements plist,

(I need to receive the message when the app is running in the background as well, but if I can't put the content-available key in the message then I wont be able to do that.)

Comment: `content-available` will not trigger `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()`, but still ask for confirming, does it fire? And which version are you using to test it?

Comment: I'm not using DidReceiveNotificationResponse().  I/m using DidReceiveRemoteNotification.  Sorry, which version of what?